# Telnet is blocked on a port (443) while still allowing web service request on the same host and port

Tags: telnet

I have been trying to connect to a partner's web service which is running on HTTPS default port 443. I had been under wrong impression that they had not open firewall ports for us because telnet from my server was unable to establish a connection. For example, I was typing:

```
$ telnet <vendor's host> 443
```

After waiting a long time (Around 15-20 seconds), it prints out that it connected but immediately also says that the connection closed:

```
Connected to <host>.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection to <host> closed by foreign host.
```

However, on running the SOAP UI from the server and hitting a URL that is hosted on the same host and port works fine.

Just wondering why telnet connection gets tripped. Is there any kind of setting possible at the server side?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're actually making a Telnet connection?  But then it closes because the server finds no interesting conversation, because the server is expecting SSL negotiations to complete.

Understand that Telnet is not very different than TCP.  [][CyberPillar: Telnet](http://cyberpillar.com/dirsver/1/mainsite/techns/netfeats/remtaccs/telnet/telnet.htm) may discuss that.)  So what would you expect the SSL server to do with a TCP connection?  In the case of an HTTPS server (which is what I'm presuming, since you mentioned TCP port 443), I would expect the HTTPS server to want to immediately perform SSL negotiation.  If a client does not successfully provide SSL negotiation, then the client may just be an attacker trying to use up the server's resources.  So, the server won't be wasting resources by responding in interesting ways (like printing out an informative message).  That would be the behavior that provides the most desirable results, most of the time.  Most connections from clients who know what they are doing will be HTTPS connections by a client that does know how to negotiate SSL.

I would expect similar results from many other protocols that are designed to use encryption.  Offhand, I don't know that this behavior is absolutely required by any specific technical specifications/requirements.  However, what I do know is that the description you provide, which notes the behavior you experienced, is really not surprising to me whatsoever.  Perhaps just from some experience I've had, it's what I would expect.  The results you describe would not be surprising to me, even if your firewall was doing nothing.  Consequently, I don't offhand know whether your firewall is effectively doing anything noteworthy with this traffic.  Maybe the firewall is blocking it, or maybe the firewall is passing it to an HTTPS server which is just handling the connection in a way that you weren't expecting.

Comment: The output shown in the original question does say `Connected to <host>`, so the socket did connect.  I think you are almost certainly correct that the SSL negotiation then fails and the connection is closed.